# Why does this golang code return 2 times instead of 5?

Tags: for-loop, go, debugging, testing

I don't have any idea.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    mySlc := []int{1, 2}
    count := 0
    num := 5
    fmt.Println(len(mySlc))
    fmt.Print("Enter Len:")
    for i := 0; i <= num-len(mySlc); i++ {
        count++
        var eded int
        fmt.Print("Enter i:")
        fmt.Scan(&eded)
        mySlc = append(mySlc, eded)
    }
    fmt.Println(mySlc, count)

}
```

I don't have any idea.
Why does this golang code return 2 times instead of 5?

Comment: The expression `i <= num-len(mySlc)` is evaluated on each iteration of the loop.  The  value if `i` increases by 1 on each iteration and the value of `num-len(mySlc)` decreases by 1 on each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's right.

- The first iteration of the loop. i=0, 0 <= 5-2, Ok. An element is added.
- The second iteration. i=1, 1 <= 5-3, Ok. An element is added.
- The third iteration. i=2, 2 <= 5-4, No Ok. The cycle ends.

Answer (score 2):

`mySlc` is being mutated during each loop iteration, and note that the `i <= num - len(mySlc)` is being evaluated on each loop run. You can view this interactively by converting this to a while-loop with

```
for {
...
}
```

and inspecting the state of `num - len(mySlc)` at each iteration.